# How do i auto-increment input id when new row appended?

Tags: jquery, html

i'm trying to assign a new id increment by 1 to my input every time i add a new input dynamically. However, my value is not incrementing as it should be. Can anyone tell whats wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="row">                 
        <i class="imgAdd">Add Input</i>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".imgAdd").click(function(){
     var count = 0;
      $(this).closest(".row").find('.imgAdd').before(
      '<input type="text" name="orderid" class="orderid" id="orderid'+ (count++) +'"></div>');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` is a local variable, you should make it global.

```
var count = 0; 
$(".imgAdd").click(function(){        
      $(this).closest(".row").find('.imgAdd').before(
      '<input type="text" name="orderid" class="orderid" id="orderid'+ (count++) +'"></div>');
);
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!. I'm so careless. How can i miss the variable is not global